# did "born and bred" originally have different meaning?

Tags: etymology, phrases

Internet searching suggests the phrase "born and bred in Boston" means the same thing as "born and raised in Boston."

But "bred" is the past-tense of "breed."

**Might "born and bred in Boston" have originally meant "born in Boston to parents who lived in Boston at the time of conception"?**

Comment: Hm. I've always mentally read it as "born and bread". As in, I was born, and then I horrifyingly transmogrified into bread. That may not be correct, but it's certainly more fun. I vote that for the official interpretation.

Comment: Related at ELL: *[Can I say “I was born in a place but bred in another place” instead of using “born and bred” in pair?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48164)*

Comment: In Britain we do not *raise* children as they do in the United States, we *bring them up*. We *raise* sheep, pigs, goats, ducks, chickens etc, and we even *raise* potatoes. But children are *brought up* and later refer to their *upbringing* rather than where they were *raised*.

Comment: @ParthianShot Mine's not nearly as fun as yours (nor any more correct), but I've always thought that the author of my school's [Fight Song](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Carolina_Tar_Heels#I.27m_a_Tar_Heel_Born) was merely taking poetic license with the natural order of these two biological events in order to make the lyrics rhyme!

Comment: @PapaPoule Indeed. Well, I know in rural Alabama the phrase "born and inbred".

Answer (score 4):

The saying **born and bred** dates back at least to the 17th century as shown in [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=born%20and%20bred&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cborn%20and%20bred%3B%2Cc0). To breed at that time already meant also to grow up ( late 14th c.) so there is not reason to suppose that the expression had originally a meaning different from the contemporary one.

[Born and bred](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/born-and-bred):

> - used to say that someone was born and grew up in a particular place, and has the typical character of someone who lives there:

[Breed](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=breed&allowed_in_frame=0) (v.): (Etymonline)

> - Old English bredan "bring young to birth, carry," also "cherish, keep warm," from West Germanic *brodjan (cognates: Old High German bruoten, German brüten "to brood, hatch"), from *brod- "fetus, hatchling," from PIE *bhreue- "burn, heat" (see brood (n.)). Original notion of the word was incubation, warming to hatch. **Sense of "grow up, be reared" ( in a clan, etc.) is late 14c.**

Comment: When I first heard this used, which would have been in the late 1940s, people in England used to say 'bred and born'. And that seems more logical than 'born and bred', since 'breed' would seem to me to have more to do with conception than with upbringing.

Comment: so WS2, are you saying that the British meaning of "bred and born in Britain" is akin to "born in Britain to parents who lived in Britain at the time of conception"? Or would 'bred and born' have same meaning as 'born and bred'?

Comment: RE: "born and bred," to WS2--you Britishers do not maintain exclusivity of the term "brought up." That term, along with "raised" and "grew up," are also used in the United States, more or less synonymously, to describe how, when and where a person has lived in her/his formative years, generally ages 0-18 years old. By the way, I was actually *born and bred* in the Greater Boston area. *Greater Boston* is a term encompassing Boston proper and its more immediate suburban environs within about 25 miles in any direction.

Answer (score 2):

According to the OED,

> ***to be born and bred***, or ***bred and born***: an alliterative phrase in which *bred* has usually sense 9, though formerly sense 1.
>
> > 1542   N. Udall tr. Erasmus *Apophthegmes* f. 133v
> >
> > > In the same Isle born, breden, and brought vp.
> >
> > a1616   Shakespeare *Twelfth Night* (1623) i. ii. 20
> >
> > > I was bred and borne Not three houres trauaile from this very place.

Sense 9 is that of animal husbandry, whereas sense 1 is of

> *trans.* Said of a female parent: To cherish (brood) in the womb or egg; to bring (offspring) forward from the germ to the birth; to hatch (young birds) from the egg; to produce (offspring, children).

This suggests that *bred and born* would indeed be more congruent with the  chronology of gravidity and parturition, but binomial word order does not depend on such things, hence *[thunder and lightning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273976)*. Or perhaps, in the reverse process of *[kith and kin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/246512/)*, people came to associate the saying with a different sense of *breed*. Right after its entry for *born and bred*, the OED attests to *breed* meaning

> 10. To train up to a state of physical or mental development. … b. To train up (young persons) in the arts of life; to educate, tutor, bring up. … †(a) To train by education, educate, teach. *Obs.*  (b) To bring up from childhood, including all the circumstances which go to form the religious persuasion, manners, position in life, and trade.

Comment: +1 for "To train up to a state of physical or mental development. …"